# Meaning of "Me cae gordo"

Tags: modismos, méxico

I know the meaning of the phrase "Me cae bien": *I like him/her* (in a strictly platonic sense), or *He leaves a good impression*

But recently I have heard the phrase *Me cae gordo* (in Mexico).  It's clearly a similar construction as the previous, but what does it mean? Where does the phrase come from?

Comment: FYI it is not exclusive of Mexico. In Colombia it is used in the same way and it is a very common expression.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From DRAE:

> [**gordo**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=JLSh4xE)
>
> **caer gordo, da a alguien otra persona**
>
> 1. loc. verb. coloq. Resultarle antipática, molesta o desagradable.

Answer (score 7):

`Me cae gordo` means exactly the opposite :

> I truly dislike him/her.

(I added the *truly* to make emphasis.) As from where the expression comes, I have no clue.

Comment: No idea where the expression comes either

Answer (score 6):

While I don't have a specific source to base my claims, I believe that the usage of `gordo` is closely related to certain meanings of [`pesado`](http://dle.rae.es/pesado) (as one would expect a fat person to be heavy in weight):

> **pesado, da.**
>
> 7. adj. Molesto, enfadoso, impertinente.
> 8. adj. Duro, violento, insufrible, difícil de soportar.

And actually a closely related phrase is [`caer pesado`](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/caer_mal#Synonyms)

Comment: En mi vida he oído la expresión de caer pesado. Caer gordo sí, pero caer pesado.no.

Comment: "Caer pesado" yo tampoco lo he oido de esa forma, pero si "ser pesado" o "andar de pesado"

Comment: Pero no es para nada lo mismo. Una novia puede ser muy pesada ( Que esté llamando cada hora), pero eso no implica ningún sentimiento negativo.

Comment: Posiblemente sea algo distinto según el país y/o la región, la expresión "caer gordo" se usa mucho en México y aquí "ser pesado" es algo mas como ser molesto tanto como "caer gordo" se usa cuando alguien te cae mal, y no como ser insistente como sería el caso del ejemplo que mencionas